# Compilation using Boost Test Unit in std c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-unit-test-framework

I'm trying to compile a very simple program using Boost Test Unit

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE My Test
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(first_test) {   int i = 1;   BOOST_CHECK(i == 1); }
```

If I compile this small program with no parameters,

```
g++ test1.cpp
```

there's no problem. But, if I try to use C++11 standard,

```
g++ test1.cpp -std=c++11
```

I get some errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp:19:0,
                 from test1.cpp:2: /usr/include/boost/test/impl/debug.ipp: En la función ‘const char* boost::debug::{anónimo}::prepare_gdb_cmnd_file(const boost::debug::dbg_startup_info&)’: /usr/include/boost/test/impl/debug.ipp:426:23: error: ‘::mkstemp’ no se ha declarado
     fd_holder cmd_fd( ::mkstemp( cmd_file_name ) );
                       ^ In file included from /usr/include/boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp:19:0,
                 from test1.cpp:2: /usr/include/boost/test/impl/debug.ipp: En la función ‘bool boost::debug::attach_debugger(bool)’: /usr/include/boost/test/impl/debug.ipp:863:34: error: ‘::mkstemp’ no se ha declarado
     fd_holder init_done_lock_fd( ::mkstemp( init_done_lock_fn ) );
                                  ^ In file included from /usr/include/boost/test/utils/runtime/cla/dual_name_parameter.hpp:19:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/test/impl/unit_test_parameters.ipp:31,
                 from /usr/include/boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp:33,
                 from test1.cpp:2: /usr/include/boost/test/utils/runtime/config.hpp: En la función ‘void boost::runtime::putenv_impl(boost::runtime::cstring, boost::runtime::cstring)’: /usr/include/boost/test/utils/runtime/config.hpp:95:51: error: ‘putenv’ no se declaró en este ámbito
     putenv( const_cast<char*>( fs.str().c_str() ) );
```

(The compiler is in spanish)

I'm using:

- Cygwin 64 bits
- Cygwin's Boost 1.59
- Cygwin's G++ 4.9.3

Any help will be welcome. Thanks.
José.-

Comment: `mkstemp` is not a C++ standard function. Have you tried `std=gnu++11` to get some extensions?

Comment: @BoPersson Works. Put your comment as answer please.
I thought that `std=c++11` and `std=gnu++11` was the same in a environment in which only gnu c++ is installed :c. Could you explain me please why this happens?

Comment: It was just a guess. The options are like "strict C++ standard" vs "some Posix and stuff added". I don't know the exact details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is a Cygwin thing. I could not reproduce it on OpenSUSE 13.2 i586 with Boost 1.54, but got the same result as yours on Cygwin Win32 with Boost 1.57. And, as *Bo Persson* suggested, also tried `std=gnu+11`.

As the compiler sayd “not *declared*” — even if you explicitly include `<stdlib.h>` which declares both `mkstemp` and `putenv`, — it seemed doubtful to me that it was all about C++ language extensions, but rather more like header file issue. Indeed, in Linux we have:

```
#if defined __USE_MISC || defined __USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED \
    || defined __USE_XOPEN2K8
# ifndef __USE_FILE_OFFSET64
extern int mkstemp (char *__template) __nonnull ((1)) __wur;
# else
#  ifdef __REDIRECT
extern int __REDIRECT (mkstemp, (char *__template), mkstemp64)
     __nonnull ((1)) __wur;
#  else
#   define mkstemp mkstemp64
#  endif
# endif
# ifdef __USE_LARGEFILE64
extern int mkstemp64 (char *__template) __nonnull ((1)) __wur;
# endif
#endif
```

But in Cygwin:

```
#ifndef __STRICT_ANSI__
#ifndef _REENT_ONLY
int _EXFUN(mkstemp,(char *));
#endif
int _EXFUN(_mkstemp_r, (struct _reent *, char *));
#endif
```

Then I added a couple of `#undef`s to your program:

```
#undef __STRICT_ANSI__
#undef _REENT_ONLY

#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE My Test
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(first_test) {   int i = 1;   BOOST_CHECK(i == 1); }
```

And could compile it fine with `std=c++11`. I have no idea how incorrect and stupid this may be, but at least it produced very similar *exe* file that only differs by 20 bytes (aside from fingerprint).